# Regex to match a "global::" prefixed fully qualified C# type name

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match fully qualified C# type names, but the + after \w+ captures too much:

```
global((::|\.)\w+(?!\s|\())+
```

Tried to play with quantifiers and negative lookahead but without success.

Online sandbox:

https://regex101.com/r/L6Y8kv/1

Sample:

```
    public global::libebur128.EBUR128StateInternal D
    {
        get
        {
            var __result0 = global::libebur128.EBUR128StateInternal.__GetOrCreateInstance(((__Internal*)__Instance)->d, false);
            return __result0;
        }
```

Result:

```
global::libebur128.EBUR128StateInterna
global::libebur128.EBUR128StateInternal.__GetOrCreateInstanc
```

Expected:

```
global::libebur128.EBUR128StateInternal
global::libebur128.EBUR128StateInternal
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\bglobal::[^\W_]+(?:\.[^\W_]+)*` https://regex101.com/r/9OrtZR/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example data, you might use:

```
\bglobal::[^\W_]+(?:\.[^\W_]+)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bglobal::` A word boundary, followed by matching `global::`
- `[^\W_]+` Match 1+ word characters excluding `_`
- `(?:\.[^\W_]+)*` Optionally repeat matching `.` and 1+ word characters excluding `_`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/9OrtZR/1).

If the last part should not be followed by `(` and you don't want to take the underscore into account, you might add a word boundary and a negative lookahead:

```
\bglobal::\w+(?:\.\w+)*\b(?!\()
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `global::` Match literally
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:\.\w+)*` Optionally repeat `.` and 1+ word chars
- `\b` A word boundary (to prevent backtracking to make the next assertion true)
- `(?!\()` Negative lookahead, assert not `(` directly to the right of the current position

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y2CSHt/1)

Comment: Looks great, how can it be upgraded so as to not assume that the method name starts with an underscore?

Comment: @aybe Can you give an example of a string that should not match?

Comment: Basically, if the last block `.abcd` is followed by either a space or an opening parenthesis, then it obviously is the method name and shall be ignored.

Comment: @aybe Like this perhaps? https://regex101.com/r/s8kvoM/1

Comment: Okay, that will do, I will try understand what you did and eventually fine adjust, thanks :)

Comment: @aybe This part `(?!\S*?\.[^\W_]+[ (])` means that it asserts that from this position there is   no part to the right that matches `.abcd` followed by either a space or `(` where the `\S*` matches non whitspace characters.

Comment: Yep but as you can see in https://regex101.com/r/s8kvoM/1, the fully qualified name isn't matched anymore in line 1. It's trickier than it seems 

Comment: Which part has to keep on being matched?

Comment: Well, as I said, it starts with `global::` then it is followed by any number of repeating `.abcd` (a dot then a word), however, if the last `.abcd` is followed by a space or an opening parenthesis then that one shall not be part of the capture. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: So like this https://regex101.com/r/emyhzK/1 Or like this `\bglobal::[^\W_]+(?:\.[^\W_]+)*\b(?![ (])` https://regex101.com/r/yMxYUN/1

Comment: Nope, seems like it's impossible with a single regex, I got it working with two: `(global::\w+(?:(?:\.\w+)+))\.\w+\(` and `(global::\w+(?:(?:\.\w+)+))\x20+\w+`. But as to combine them, the regex engine becomes crazy . I might just do search for matches twice and that will be end of the story.

Comment: @aybe If you can create a regex101 link and provide the cases that sholluld and should not match I can help you finding a solution.

Comment: I finally got it right without assuming underscores, see my answer, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @aybe So you mean just like this? `\bglobal::\w+(?:\.\w+)*\b(?!\()` https://regex101.com/r/Y2CSHt/1

Comment: Yes, it's simpler than mine, thank you for your time! 